# Single line chunk re-assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

As shown in the following code, I have a chunk list `x` and the full list `h`. I want to reassign back the values stored in `x` in the correct positions of `h`.

```
index = 0
for t1 in range(lbp, ubp):
   h[4 + t1] = x[index]
   index = index + 1
```

Does anyone know how to write it in a **single line/expression**?

Disclaimer: This is part of a bigger project and I simplified the questions as much as possible. You can expect the matrix sizes to be correct but if you think I am missing something please ask for it. For testing you can use the following variable values:

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = [20, 21]
lbp = 2
ubp = 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slice assignment to expand on the left-hand side and assign your `x` list directly to the indices of `h`, e.g.:

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = [20, 21]
lbp = 2
ubp = 4     
h[4 + lbp:4 + ubp] = x  # or better yet h[4 + lbp:4 + lbp + len(x)] = x
print(h)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 21, 9, 10]
```

I'm not really sure why are you adding `4` to the indexes in your loop nor what `lbp` and `ubp` are supposed to mean, tho. Keep in mind that when you select a range like this, the list you're assigning to the range has to be of the same length as the range.

Comment: I just simplified my use case with numbers to make it easier to understand. I'll take care about the list ranges. But that is what I was looking for. Thanks!