# Non-contiguous single line chunk re-assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a follow-up question. Previously I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505787/single-line-chunk-re-assignment/50505969#50505969) how to assign in a single line a chunk list to the full list.

Now I need to perform the same assignment but when the accesses to the full list are not contiguous. So, as shown in the following code, I have a chunk list x and the full list h. I want to reassign back the values stored in x in the correct positions of h **when h is not accessed contiguously**.

```
index = 0
for t1 in range(lbp, ubp):
   h[1 + 2*t1] = x[index]
   index = index + 1
```

Does anyone know how to write it in a **single line/expression**?

As before, for testing purposes you can use:

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = [20, 21]
lbp = 2
ubp = 4
```

And the expected result is:

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 7, 21, 9, 10]
```

Disclaimer: This is part of a bigger project and I simplified the questions as much as possible. You can expect the matrix sizes to be correct but if you think I am missing something please ask for it.

Comment: I don't find it at all obvious what you are attempting to do here. Could you please make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slice assignment to do this efficiently and compactly.

```
h = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = [20, 21]
lbp = 2
ubp = 4
h[2*lbp + 1: 2*ubp + 1: 2] = x
print(h)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 7, 21, 9, 10]
```